# A basic opamp configuration which resembles the non inverting one

Tags: operational-amplifier

In the following picture, the second circuit is a non inverting opamp, the gain of which is well known to be \$A_v = 1 + R_3/R_4\$ and the demonstration of this formula can be easily found on many websites.

My problem is with the first circuit in the figure which makes me a little bit confused as it looks different from the second one, furthermore the voltage gain I calculated is \$A_V = 1/(1 + R_1/R_2)\$, but I found on some web sites that still this configuration is a "non inverting opamp" with a gain \$A_V = 1 + R_1/R_2\$.

If I am right, and this is not a non inverting opamp, still I found such configuration in some other cases such as in instrumentation amplifiers. So the question is: is this another well known opamp configuration?

[image]

Comment: It's a unity gain buffer with a 50 ohm load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first circuit there is almost zero current flowing through R1 so the voltage at IN<sub>-</sub> = the voltage at the top of R2. It is the same as OP2 with R3 = 0. You have created a unity-gain voltage follower with an unnecessary load on the output.

Comment: Both circuits will not work because the 50 ohm resistor values are much too low. most opamps have a minimum allowed load of 2k ohms.

Comment: @Audioguru: Agreed but I felt it was out of scope of the question.

Comment: @Audioguru Not necessarily. APEX makes op amps that can drive a 50 ohm load. It's always dangerous to generalize like that.

Comment: even out of the main issue, still the resistores dimensioning is an interesting topic. I argue I should have to figure out the range of resistances from the datasheet, isn't it?

Comment: While he is the king of such out-of-scope statements, he said "most opamps", which is correct.  The world consumes more LM324/358's in a week than Apex's entire product line sells in a year.

Comment: @AnalogKid No, you are changing the wording. The comment said "both circuits will not work because the 50 ohm resistor values are much too low". That statement is false. The next phrase "most opamps **have a minimum allowed load of 2k ohms" might** be true but it does **not** state that some opamps have an allowed load of **less than 50 ohms**.